# How to solve position issue in ie7 using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I put 'div' tag in 'h1' tag. and add it to following css. I want to place this 'div' tag to bottom left corner of 'h1' tag. It's working fine in mordern browser but in ie7 'div' tag leave space from left side.

Whats wrong in my code.

HTML:

```
<h1>
    <a href="#">Web Design Resources</a>
    <div></div>
</h1>
```

css:

```
h1 {
border-bottom: 1px solid #797979;
position: relative;
}
h1 a {
margin: 7px 0 0px 0;
padding: 0px 0 1px 0px;
font-size: 1.12em;
}
#innerFooter h1 div {
height: 1px;
width: 20%;
background: #ffffff;
position: absolute;
bottom: -1px;
}
```

Thanking you.

Comment: The `<div>` tag shouldn't really be inside the `<h1>` tag... `<div>` is a container, so really, the `<h1>` should sit inside the `<div>` and then you can try and fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `h1` is layout parent, you only need to add `left: 0` to the `#innerFooter h1 div` rules.